# 3D Model with use of textures [Android]

Tags: android, 3d, textures, texture-mapping, min3d

I am trying to find approaches on stamping multiple textures on an object (3D .obj) Android. But, I am unable to do so, I have tried min3d but not sure if it is the right way to do it?

Is there anything available around which is similar to this? Or How Should I approach this UI? Below is the UI of model and how I want to stamp an "image"/texture on it, in addition I want to change the color of the model / add text on it.

In addition, I am planning to give touches on it, by stamping username/label/textview at the back of the model by using rotation through touches.

Please guide, which SDK should I use on Android, what is the best approach to do it.

[image: Actual Model]

[image: This is how I want?]

Comment: Extrusion Deption and viewRenderable you can use over a specific node on the 3d model.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is basically just rendering textures on a given 3D mesh, as far as I can see. You could take multiple approaches for this: The simplest being just texturing the actual object, but a more complicated approach could involve rendering the object and "stamp"&text textures separately, giving the illusion of being overlayed (Not preferable though, as this will be difficult to manage correctly).
For texturing, you can either attempt rendering different textures after each other (First the background, then the stamp, then the text), or combining the different elements into one texture (pre-processing) before rendering.

I recommend having a look at the following posts and articles:

- [OpenGL ES (which can do everything you want to do, but has a decently steep learning curve)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl)
- Switch to a different 3D rendering engine if you find it too difficult to use your current one ([Many options, although most are fullblown game engines](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/2))
- [Loading 3D objects and textures for OpenGL ES rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172201/loading-3d-objects-and-textures-for-opengl-es-rendering)
- Check out the following git snippets and articles on texturing in min3d: [this](https://github.com/mengdd/min3d/blob/master/sampleProjects/min3dSampleProject1/src/min3d/sampleProject1/ExampleMultiTexture.java), [this article](http://www.mat-d.com/site/android-min3d-quick-tip-changing-textures-of-3ds-and-obj-3d-models-at-runtime/), [this article on object loading](http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-load-a-3d-obj-model-with-min3d-for-android/)

You did not provide any code displaying your current attempts, so it is difficult to say what exactly your problem is, and how to solve it. If you edit your question you might receive more concrete solutions besides just links to potentially helpful resources.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps working with the OpenGL ES 2.0 api might be an option. Take a look this repo here called the [Android 3D Model Viewer](https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer) which makes use of it, it might help you out.